# Entity in application write in uppercase

Tags: semantics

I work on a big interface with many objects. A colleague thinks we should write the objects with the first letter in uppercase. Example with the entity car: This rule will remove all the Cars. Continue?"

For him, it's help user to understand "here, it's the entity Car in the application, not the vehicle".

Personally, I don't like this, I prefer the lowercase. For me, uppercase is for proper name and it's confusing.

What do you think?

(Sorry for my english, im not very good xD)

Comment: There are other ways to increase visibility like: bold, italics, color change. Why do your colleague prefer uppercase first letter over the other methods?

Comment: It's a good question. I think we could do that, provide a "more important" style for each message location. But personnaly I am not sure it's the entity to highlight..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arbitrarily capitalizing letters is a typographic mistake: there are specific capitalization rules, and not following them is similar to having typos. So no, your colleague is not right.

If, for instance, your goal is to show the user that clicking on a button will remove all the cars, but not vehicles, keeping canoes, balloons, rockets and quadracycles unaffected, then you may simply add a hint which may disambiguate the consequences of the action. For instance, what about:

> This rule will remove all the 283 cars (of 1.424 vehicles).

Another way is to actually *show* what would be removed. For instance:

> This rule will remove the following cars:
>
> **[image1] [image2] [image3] [image4]** [show more](https://example.com)

Finally, following Alan Cooper's *Do, don't ask* model, you can simply remove all the cars, and show the list of vehicles without the cars, while keeping an *Undo* action nearby. This approach is visually effective, as it makes it possible for the user to take an action, see immediately its consequences, and revert if this is not the action the user wanted to perform.

---

As a side note, I don't understand your *“Continue?”* If it's a confirmation dialog, you definitively need to read Alan Cooper's *About Face*, as well as [my answer on a related subject](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/106039/6605).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! We do that (Recall the name of the entity) most of the time. But in this case we can't because there are a lot cars. Your solution to write the number of entities is a good idea but we can't because there are millions of cars and we don't want do a request. (it will too long). About the "continue" it's not into a dialog, it's a rollover on the row. To me more clear, a screen: http://www.zupimages.net/up/17/24/5yta.png